# Creating a loading image while ajax function loads

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a loading image while ajax loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824291/creating-a-loading-image-while-ajax-loads)

`enter code here`This is the code i have, im trying to insert a image to show that ajax is loading bt i just cant get this right, tried a lot of possible ways but it just aint working, any suggestions on wat to do?

```
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('main_result');
                ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        $("#main_result").empty().html('<img src="loading.gif" />');

        var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
        var brand = document.getElementById('brand').value;
        var item = document.getElementById('item').value;
        var queryString = "&category=" + category + "&brand="+ brand +"&item="+ item;
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "main_search_special.php?section=special" + queryString, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
```